# How can I test this custom Action that extends ActionBuilder?

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to write a unit test to test my custom action builder.

Once I set the ActionWithSession as in instance in my test, how do I instantiate it like it would be in a controller?

How can I test for the edge cases if it redirects or returns with the Session?

```
class SessionAwareRequest[A](val context: MyContext, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

class ActionWithSession @Inject()(siteConfig: SiteConfig, userService: UserService)
  extends ActionBuilder[SessionAwareRequest] {

  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (SessionAwareRequest[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
    val session = loadSession(request)

    if(session.isDefined) {
      val result: Future[Result] = block(new SessionAwareRequest(session.get, request))
      result.map(_.withCookies(CookieHelper.newSession(session.get)(request)))
    }
    else {
      Future.successful(Results.Redirect(routes.MessagesController.show("error!"))) 

  }

  def loadSession(requestHeader: RequestHeader): Option[MySession] = {
    ...
      Some(MySession(...))
    else
      None
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Play 2.3, you should be able to utilize the `PlaySpecification` trait, which provides a `call` method to test Actions. Have a look at the [Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaTestingWithSpecs2), especially the section about "Unit Testing EssentialAction
".

Here's an artificial, minimal example based on the code you posted. It basically just checks whether the request headers contains a "foo" field and if so, returns OK together with an additional cookie "baz" that is added via the custom action builder. If the "foo" header is missing it returns BadRequest. Hope it helps.

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.test.{FakeRequest, PlaySpecification}
import scala.concurrent.Future

class ActionSpec extends PlaySpecification {
  case class MySession()

  class SessionAwareRequest[A](val context: MySession, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

  object ActionWithSession extends ActionBuilder[SessionAwareRequest] {

    def loadSession(requestHeader: RequestHeader): Option[MySession] = {
      if (requestHeader.headers.get("foo").isDefined)
        Some(MySession())
      else
        None
    }

    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (SessionAwareRequest[A]) => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
      val session = loadSession(request)

      if (session.isDefined) {
        val result: Future[Result] = block(new SessionAwareRequest(session.get, request))
        result.map(_.withCookies(Cookie("baz", "quux")))
      } else {
        Future.successful(Results.BadRequest)
      }
    }
  }

  "My custom action" should {

    "return HTTP code 400 in case the request header does not contain a 'foo' field" in {
      val foo = call(ActionWithSession { request =>
        Results.Ok("Yikes")
      }, FakeRequest())
      status(of = foo) must beEqualTo(BAD_REQUEST)
      cookies(of = foo).get("baz") must beNone
    }

    "return HTTP code 200 in case the request header does contain a 'foo' field" in {
      val foo = call(ActionWithSession { request =>
        Results.Ok("Yikes")
      }, FakeRequest().withHeaders("foo" -> "bar"))
      status(of = foo) must beEqualTo(OK)
      cookies(of = foo).get("baz") must beSome
    }
  }

}
```